# syn match lines which contain only / but not //

Tags: vim, colors, syntax-highlighting

To match lines which  contain forward slash(`/`), we can use the following in syntax file

```
syntax match colorpath "\v/.*$" #highlight link colorpath Comment1
```

to match lines which have double forward slash(`//`), we can use the same statement

```
syntax match colorpath2 "\v//.*$" #highlight link colorpath2 Comment2
```

but the first part overwrites the second one as shown in image1.
Also, in line 1 pathA is not colored, if I use "\v.*/.*$" it will color entire line .

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Is there any way so that I can differentiate the two lines as shown in image2?

Comment: have a look at regex lookaheads =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple problem of adapting the regular expressions to your needs.

To include `pathA` before the `/`, you need to match it. `.*/.*$` will match the entire line (as you've already found out); the `.` matches *anything* (also whitespace), and the `*` is a *greedy* match. You have to ask yourself which characters can be contained inside a *colorpath*, and which cannot. Let's assume that it can consist of anything but whitespace. The regular expression atom is `\S` (and equivalent `[^[:space:]]` inside a collection). With this, we arrive at:

```
syntax match colorpath "\S*/.*$"
```

Second problem is that this obscures the *colorpath2*, because *colorpath2* is a subset of *colorpath*. We need to make the sets of matches disjunct, for example like this:

```
syntax match colorpath "\S*[^/[:space:]]/[^/].*$"
```

This basically says: Any non-whitespace, no slash (and still no whitespace) before the slash, then the single slash, followed by no slash, to the end of the line.
The previous command only works if there are indeed path characters before the slash (so it fails on `/pathX`). To fix that, we have to add branches for matching at the start of the line, and immediately after whitespace (of course, only if your syntax actually allows those places):

```
syntax match colorpath "\%(\S*[^/[:space:]]\|^\|\s\zs\)/[^/].*$"
```

Another way to express this is with *negative lookbehind and lookahead*; this is less readable, but avoids the manual joining of the `\S` and `[^/]` as in the previous command, and it automatically handles the corner case of a single slash at the start, without any additional branches.

```
syntax match colorpath "\S*/\@<!//\@!.*$"
```

This is because the atoms only assert a match, but do not consume anything. See `:help /zero-width` for details.